# Coldfusion Ping or check external DSN is online

Tags: coldfusion, dsn

apologies if this has been asked before but i couldn't find anything that could answer my question.

We have a Coldfusion script that runs from our website and queries an external dsn in our office.

Problem is that the server is located in rural england and sometimes the server is unavailable (thanks to our unreliable UK ISP!!)

Is there a command in coldfusion that could query or ping an external dsn so I can wrap the whole script in a cfif statement and get an email if it fails to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension to a comment on duncan's answer, but can't put code blocks in comments, so...

```
<cfset TargetHost = "0.0.0.0" />
<cfset PingAttempts = 4 />

<cfif find('Windows',Server.Os.Name)>
    <cfset Args = "-n #PingAttempts# #TargetHost#" />
<cfelse>
    <cfset Args = "-c #PingAttempts# #TargetHost#" />
</cfif>

<cfexecute name="ping" arguments=#Args# variable="PingResult" timeout=10 />

<cfif PingResult CONTAINS "100% packet loss"
    OR PingResult CONTAINS "100% loss"
    >
    [send alert]
</cfif>

<cfdump var=#PingResult# />
```

(In general, I'd still go with checking via an actual query - pinging only confirms the machine is online, not that the database is responding.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, really appreciate your persistence in getting this sorted!

Answer (score 2):

JFGI:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\winnt\system32\ping.exe" arguments="#request.myIP#"  variable="myPing" timeout="8"></cfexecute>
```

Or on Linux/Unix:

```
<cfexecute name="ping" arguments="#request.myIP# -c 3" timeout="10" variable="myPing" />

<cfif myPing contains "Request timed out">
  <cfmail ...>
<cfelse>
  [do something else]
</cfif>
```

Or http://www.bennadel.com/blog/751-Learning-ColdFusion-8-Ping-User-Defined-Function-Inspired-By-Ray-Camden-.htm

Comment: That kinda assumes Windows, and breaking out into the shell if less then ideal. Is there no Java solution to this (on my phone so can't be stuffed googling). Ben's solution poor because `ping` doesn't use HTTP. Will google when I'm in front of a computer, but I think the OP could probably do that themselves.

Comment: Just had a quick look, it seems there's no _reliable_ Java solution; there is `isReachable(timeout)` for `java.net.InetAddress` but it seems to have issues on Windows. :/

Comment: Thanks and we do actually use Linux so the windows ping is out.

Comment: ... so Linux ping is in.  Updated my answer

Comment: Thankyou, the ping on Linux works great. How would you suggest I use the variable in a cfif statement please? So if the ping is successful it does one thing and if not it emails me to let me know?

Comment: Check the contents of the results variable.  I'm not 100% sure what that would be on Linux, but guess it's similar to Windows.  I'll update my answer

Comment: Hi Duncan, probably better with '100% packet loss'

Comment: You don't need to specify the absolute path to `ping` on Windows (it's in `%PATH%`), so can do an OS-independent version just by changing between n/c for the arguments... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250745/coldfusion-ping-or-check-external-dsn-is-online#18254307) for code.

Answer (score 2):

To find out if the datasource works just try to use it:

```
<cftry>
    <cfquery datasource="external" timeout=10 >
        SELECT 1
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch>
        <cfif [timeout error]>
            <cfmail ...>No response in 10 seconds</cfmail>
        <cfelse>
            [do something else]
        </cfif>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Since that doesn't appear to work, another option might be:

```
<cfthread action="run" name="QueryThread">
    <cfquery datasource="external">SELECT 1</cfquery>
</cfthread>
<cfthread action="run" name="CheckThread">
    <cfthread action="sleep" duration="10000" />
    <cfif cfthread.QueryThread.Status NEQ 'COMPLETED'>
        [handle error]
        <cfthread action="terminate" name="QueryThread" />
    </cfif>
</cfthread>
```

Same concept, but using multiple threads should mean that even if the query is too deep for CF to break, you can still trigger the email sending after ten seconds.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I tried this and unfortunately it did not work quite as well because the datasource took sometime to respond despite the timeout.

Comment: Hrm, in that case you could probably put the query in one cfthread, then have a second cfthread that sleeps for 10 seconds before checking if the other thread has finished or not - if it's still running, terminate it and send the email.